# How to use cin for exit in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code from a book about Algorithms by Robert Sedwick.

How do i break a for loop in the following statement `if (!(cin >> a[N])) break;`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int compare(const void *i, const void *j)
  { return strcmp(*(char **)i, *(char **)j); }
int main()
  { const int Nmax = 1000;
    const int Mmax = 10000;
    char* a[Nmax]; int N;
    char buf[Mmax]; int M = 0;
    for (N = 0; N < Nmax; N++)
      {
        a[N] = &buf[M];
        if (!(cin >> a[N])) break; 
        M += strlen(a[N])+1;
      }
    // std::cout << "Number of strings entered are " << N << std::endl;
    qsort(a, N, sizeof(char*), compare);
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) 
      cout << a[i] << endl;
  }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a very unclear question. What are you trying to do and what doesn't work about it?

Comment: I think the question is in the title, not the content of the message. It appears Bo has answered it well below.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you type the input at the console, you have to enter the end-of-file code.

For Linux this would be `Ctrl+D`, and for Windows `Ctrl+Z`.

Comment: worth mentioning that the alternative is to pipe (`|`) or extract a file (`<`) at the shell.